# validating email address using AJAX

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

Is there an easy way to check an email address is valid using Ajax? I'm using the `sfValidatortEmail` widget currently and this only shows an error message on submitting the form.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you know how to write ajax requests. In the action you'd have something like

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
  // handle ajax check
  try{
    $validator = new sfValidatorEmail();
    $validator->clean($request->getParameter('email'));
    // good to go
  } catch(sfValidatorError $e){
    // invalid email
    $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(400);
  }
} else {
  // handle normal post
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to add some Javascript/Jquery to fire an Ajax request to check the email, possibly linked to when the user clicks out of the email input box (blur function). This would be separate from your form class (assuming that the form has other elements too), but you could use the same action to handle the request if you wish:

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
  // handle ajax check
} else {
  // handle normal post
}
```